How do I verify if a file has a authenticode certificate or not using signify library (or any other library if you prefer that) in python?

import os
import signify
from signify.authenticode import SignedPEFile

file = open(r"C:\Users\rajha\OneDrive\Desktop\result.txt", "r", errors='ignore')




while True:
    content = file.readline()
    
    if content == "":
        break
    
    output = content.casefold().find("C:\\".casefold())
    if output != -1:
        susFile = content[output::]
        
        if os.path.isfile((susFile.strip())):
            print(susFile)
            try:
                x = pefile.verify()
                print(x)
            except Exception as e:
                pass
            
           

            else:
                pass
        




    
file.close()


The output is:
C:\Users\rajha\OneDrive\Desktop\Academy Dump\Anydesk.exe

c:\Users\rajha\OneDrive\Desktop\Academy Dump\Anydesk.exe

C:\Users\rajha\OneDrive\Desktop\Academy Dump\Anydesk.exe

C:\Users\rajha\OneDrive\Desktop\Academy Dump\Anydesk.exe

C:\Users\rajha\OneDrive\Desktop\Academy Dump\Anydesk.exe

C:\Users\rajha\OneDrive\Desktop\Academy Dump\Anydesk.exe

C:\Users\rajha\OneDrive\Desktop\tcpview64.exe

C:\Users\rajha\OneDrive\Desktop\Academy Dump\Receipt_4_15_2024 12_00_00 AM.pdf

C:\Users\rajha\Downloads\12404136312.pdf




Here, I am expecting to see a boolean (x) if the file has a certificate or not (true below tcpview64.exe and false below others)
I tried using lief, signify, winsign but failed maybe I am just too bad at reading docs lol (I started programming 2 days ago)
Now, the goal is to extract file paths from a txt file (it does very well, named susFile) and now, if you could, write code that returns a boolean (name it anything like x or sigStatus isSigned) on whether the file has a signature or not. I will link the
Maybe this helps:
https://winsign.readthedocs.io/en/latest/winsign.html
https://signify.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authenticode.html
I will be glad if you help!
Thanks in advance!
